# Trouble with URI parsing C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to create a text field that can be typed in but also accepts a dialogue box selection, so that a Contact can be attached to an outlook task.
I'm basically trying to recreate the outlook forms contact field using c# and WPF. By which I mean there is a contact button that opens a dialogue to select a contact. That contact is then shown in the text field and is interactable and shows the contact details.

I've had success with the *ShowNamesDialougue* taking the names selected and writing them to a TextBox.

I have tried to pass a hyperlink to a TextBox and a RichtextBox, learning that the TextBox doesn't support it and then getting stuck with parsing the URI of the ContactItem.

```
foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in snd.Recipients)
{
    Hyperlink hyperKontakt = new Hyperlink(new Run(recipient.Name));
    hyperKontakt.NavigateUri = new Uri(contactsFolder.FolderPath *contactname*);                                
    HLTextBox.CaretPosition.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(hyperKontakt);
}
```

**contactsFolder**

```
 Outlook.Folder contactsFolder = _currentTaskItem.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts) as Outlook.Folder;
```

The error is ***System.UriFormatException***: 'Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.'

The value is the Folderpath property of the oldefaultcontacts folder.

```
new Uri(contactsFolder.FolderPath);
```

It Looks Like This in the Debugger **\\hargreaves@company.de\contacts**. I've tried looking for a fully qualified path, but always have trouble with what exactly MAPI is and where it resides.

Comment: Can you show the value that you try to pass in Uri constructor ?

Comment: YOo can make a valid url if you prefix the address with mailto:, but you really need to use the rich text editor. Not a quick one afternoon project...

Comment: The value is the Folderpath property of the oldefaultcontacts folder. It Looks Like This in the Debugger **\\hargreaves@company.de\contacts**. I've tried looking for a fully qualified path, but always have trouble with what exactly MAPI is and where it resides.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Thanks for the advice. Using mailto and streamlining my URI a bit I have the Hyperlink printed as a hyperlink, but it lacks functionality. It's a step forward though thanks. Now I can keep going.